# Make an ASP.net Label with scroll bars scroll to the end using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, controls, scroll

I have a an asp.net label control on my page.

I have set the style to overflow: auto.

What i would like to know, is when there is a lot of text in my label and the vertical scroll bar is showing, is there away i can scroll to the end of the label using javascript?

I would like the user to always see the bottom section of the label.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
yourSpan.scrollTop = yourSpan.scrollHeight;
```